# Allow user to save a html/php/css page as a pdf?

Tags: php, html, css, pdf-generation

I have a "calculator" page that calculates a load of maths based on what the user inputs. The user can then click "get results" to show their full calculations.

I then have a button - "save as pdf" which I want it to allow the user to save a pdf of their results.

It's a combination of html, php, css combined with Wordpress.

How can I (on click) convert the results to a pdf and allow the user to save?

**p.s I know this been asked a few times but I can't seem to find the correct answer or a working version... or a tool with good documentation for me to follow!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check also [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: Please provide [more substantive details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72002/141525) rather than just posting a link.

Comment: I wrote that with my smartphone in a train, like now.

Answer (score 1):

Generally these things are solved on the server. Clicking the link would trigger a redirect to the php page and in general instead of writing output to a webpage, you write output to a pdf stream (still arrives in the browser but the browser knows it as a pdf).

you do this by changing the response headers. you could use [this library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) to write out the pdf file

Comment: Is there not something that will produce a pdf on the fly when a button is clicked on my website?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ make sis pretty simple, you could do a curl request to the page, and send it to the library.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for. I want a button on a website that when clicked will produce a pdf for the user. Correct me if I'm wrong but this seems to be producing a pdf from a html file locally on your computer.

Comment: On button click, you could fetch the contents of the site you want with Curl or fsocket, and then you can create the pdf and display it.